# Do Elixir functions have a maximum airty?

Tags: function, elixir, variadic-functions

Is there an upper limit to the number of arguments a function can accept? This doesn't count pattern matching. E.g. a function defined like `fn ([arg1, arg2, arg3], arg4)` only counts as 2.

If there is not an upper limit, does Elixir also support variadic functions?

Comment: I don't know if this covers the definition of variadic functions, but you can provide default values. `def foo(bar, baz \\ []) ...` defines the function `foo`, and it can be called with either one or two arguments. If it is called with one, the value of `baz` will be an empty list. I'm not sure if there is a limit on the number of arguments a function can take.

Comment: Note that you can simulate a variadic function by passing one of the arguments as a list--exactly the way you mention in your question.  That is, passing a list and then using each element in the list as a parameter gives you the ability to have varying numbers of arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Elixir runs on top of Erlang for which there seems to be a maximum arity of **255**
See this page: http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html
and search down to the table containing the row:
    `arity()    0..255`

**Confirmatory Update:**
Attempting to compile a function with 255 parameters works.

Attempting to compile a function with 256 parameters give the following compilation error:

```
== Compilation error in file arity.ex ==
** (CompileError) arity.ex:3: too many arguments (256) - maximum allowed is 255
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
** (CompileError)  compile error
    (iex) lib/iex/helpers.ex:183: IEx.Helpers.c/2
```

Test done in Elixir Shell on Windows10 x64 using `c "arity.ex"` where the contents of `arity.ex` (plus or minus a parameter) is:

```
defmodule Test do
 def arity(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18, p19, p20, p21, p22, p23, p24, p25, p26, p27, p28, p29, p30, p31, p32, p33, p34, p35, p36, p37, p38, p39, p40, p41, p42, p43, p44, p45, p46, p47, p48, p49, p50, p51, p52, p53, p54, p55, p56, p57, p58, p59, p60, p61, p62, p63, p64, p65, p66, p67, p68, p69, p70, p71, p72, p73, p74, p75, p76, p77, p78, p79, p80, p81, p82, p83, p84, p85, p86, p87, p88, p89, p90, p91, p92, p93, p94, p95, p96, p97, p98, p99, p100, p101, p102, p103, p104, p105, p106, p107, p108, p109, p110, p111, p112, p113, p114, p115, p116, p117, p118, p119, p120, p121, p122, p123, p124, p125, p126, p127, p128, p129, p130, p131, p132, p133, p134, p135, p136, p137, p138, p139, p140, p141, p142, p143, p144, p145, p146, p147, p148, p149, p150, p151, p152, p153, p154, p155, p156, p157, p158, p159, p160, p161, p162, p163, p164, p165, p166, p167, p168, p169, p170, p171, p172, p173, p174, p175, p176, p177, p178, p179, p180, p181, p182, p183, p184, p185, p186, p187, p188, p189, p190, p191, p192, p193, p194, p195, p196, p197, p198, p199, p200, p201, p202, p203, p204, p205, p206, p207, p208, p209, p210, p211, p212, p213, p214, p215, p216, p217, p218, p219, p220, p221, p222, p223, p224, p225, p226, p227, p228, p229, p230, p231, p232, p233, p234, p235, p236, p237, p238, p239, p240, p241, p242, p243, p244, p245, p246, p247, p248, p249, p250, p251, p252, p253, p254, p255, p256 ) do 
  IO.puts( "hello world" )
 end
end
```

Comment: Do Elixir functions compile down to Erlang functions then? Why would this limit apply to Elixir as well?

Comment: Elixir - like Erlang - gets transformed into Erlang AST (abstract syntax tree) which then gets compiled to byte code for the the Erlang Virtual Machine (BEAM). My guess is that the Erlang arity  at the AST stage follows that of Erlang, and so Elixir has to do that too. Let's hope an Erlang expert steps in to confirm/deny that.

Comment: I found something that seems to suggest just what you've said… I'll hold off accepting for just a bit longer to see if we get something a little more satisfying. As it stands, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

> If there is not an upper limit, does Elixir also support variadic functions?

The Beam does not support variadic functions. This is inherited from Prolog actually.

Elixir manages to fake it by creating a second function that calls the first so take this example. If you were to look at the compiled code you will find that there are 2 functions `count/1` and `count/2`

```
def count(start , end \\ 10), do: ...
```

If you were to decompile it you would find code sort of like this

```
def count(start), do: count(start, 10)
def count(start, end), do: ...
```